# Postgresql server not started in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, postgresql, database

My problem is after postgresql installed try to configure postgresql database it's show error message like below:

```
dineshlap@ss-laptop:~$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

and i tried lot of solutions from internet. but, nothing worked for me! :(

if you know the solution for this problem please, answer this post!

**Note : I'm using ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) and postgresql 9.3**

Comment: Did you modify the **postgresql.conf** file in **/etc/postgresql/9.3**? The line **listen_addresses = 'localhost'** must be uncommented (without #).

Comment: @xunilk thanks for your response! i tried but, same problem occurs!

Comment: Uninstall postgresql with purge and clean and try to install it again. I had a similar problem in Debian and I solved it in this way.

Comment: I solved my issue after correcting the `pg_hba.conf` file. I had removed the CIDR block info from the bindings section.

Answer (score 28):

Just try to restart

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

this worked for me :)

Comment: its asking for password. what's the default password here?

Comment: @PranavSingh that's your sudo password nothing to do with psql

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu16.04  and 9.3

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql-9.3.service
```

Maybe you find out service before restarting server

```
service --status-all
```

Comment: This question is about 14.04, so you can't call `systemctl`. The other answer  recommends restart. Seems very odd to include a version number in the command also - is this really needed?

Comment: My ubuntu is 16.04 on ubuntu 14.* try like "sudo service xyz start"

Answer (score 0):

In some case you may have permission issue. I create a  shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R $User:$User /var/run/postgresql
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

replace $User with your username, and execute the file (assuming the file name is `postgresql.sh`):

```
sudo ./postgresrun.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. after running

```
systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service
```

It showed the following error

> data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main" has group or world
>   access

---

### SOLUTION

so I ran:

```
sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
```

Then I restarted:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql@9.6-main.service
```

running `sudo systemctl restart postgresql@9.6-main.service` showed my service active and running!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one sir,

Edited your `pg_hba.conf` and add your host address :

```
local    all    postgres                     peer
host     all    all         127.0.0.1/24     md5
```

and also edited your `postgres.conf`add your queue with :

```
listen_addresses = " * "
```

and then restart your service :

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

see your log output said what the miracled:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

Hope this helps sir.